# How to compare different hrefs on a button using an if-statement in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, compare

I have Button A with href "www.A.com".
Im trying to figure out condition to achieve this:

If button's href != "www.A.com", then function rewritte button's href to "www.A.com".

I imagine whole function like this:

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("button A");
var y = "www.A.com";


window.onload = function() {
    if (x.href != y){
    document.getElementById("button A").href="www.A.com"; 
 }
}
</script>
```

Im kind of new to coding in JavaScript, so maybe I'm absolutely wrong.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you tested this?  Does it not work in some way?  (Aside from the fact that an `id` shouldn't have a space in it...)

Comment: You most likely want to use `.getAttribute("href")`, `.href` returns the full URL path (including `https://`), whereas `getAttribute()` returns what's set as the `href` value. Maybe share your HTML code so we can get a better idea of your issue?

Comment: If it's not A then make it A - is the same as if it's *is* A make it A - so just make it A and forget about the `if`

Comment: A button has no `href` attribute.

Comment: A button can have a `href` attribute but meanless.

Comment: Please include your HTML.  As noted, an `href` on a *button* has no effect, but an href on an `A` does - so it could be that your html is `<button><a href=...` (despite that itself being invalid HTML) - hence your attempt at using a *selector* in `getElementById` - which could be the part you're getting wrong.

Comment: Or it could be how you're testing if it works (by clicking it and expecting it to relocate to the `href`, which it won't).

Answer (score 1):

welcome to stack overflow, Your code looks almost correct, but the id shouldn't have a space `button A` try to put it as `buttonA`

and `href` returnning full url including `http://` so you shoud make your y variable:

```
var y = "http://www.A.com";
```

and inside load function:
document.getElementById("button A").href= y;

Answer (score 0):

You should not use any **space** in id, Try changing `button A` into `buttonA`

**Check out this, it may solve your problem.**

```js
var x = document.getElementById("buttonA");
var y = "https://www.A.com";

window.onload = function(){
    if(x.href != y){
        x.href = y;
    }
}
```

```html
<a id="buttonA" href="https://www.google.com">BUTTON</a>
```